# ORDER BY `sort` DESC

Tags: mysql

Выводит `3,2,1,0,0,0...` как вывести `1,2,3,0,0,0...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `field1`, `field2`, `your_field`
FROM `table`
ORDER BY IF(`your_field` = ?, 1, 0), your_field ASC
```

Где вместо `?` значение, которое должно быть в конце. В Вашем случае это ноль